# Pycharm "unresolved reference" on join of os.path

Tags: python, pycharm, os.path

After upgrade pycharm to 2018.1, and upgrade python to 3.6.5, pycharm reports "unresolved reference 'join'". The last version of pycharm doesn't show any warning for the line below:

```
from os.path import join, expanduser
```

May I know why?

(I used python 3.6.? before)

I tried almost everything I can find, such as delete and recreate interpreter, invalidate cache and restart, delete and recreate virtualenv... how do I fix this?

(I can run my program without any error.)

Comment: Have you tried deleting the folder ~/.PyCharmxxxx.xx/system/python_stubs as mentioned in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311954/pycharm-warns-for-unresolved-reference-builtin-datetime-module

Comment: I checked there is no folder ".PyCharmxxx" under my home directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [weird behavior when importing os.path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49617465/weird-behavior-when-importing-os-path)

Comment: the same problem for a single and new python file.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, it seems that PyCharm will try to evaluate the path to an existing file/folder, which in some cases will not exist and thus create this warning.

It's not very useful when you are building a path for something that's supposed to be created, because obviously it will not exist yet, but PyCharm will still complain.

You could try clicking on File > Invalidate Caches > Invalidate and Restart. This worked for me.

[edit] It will come back tho, not much else to do.

Answer (score -1):

Check that pycharms is using the correct interpreter.

Comment: Since the program runs without an error this cannot be the issue. Besides, `os.path.join` should be available independent of python interpreter used