# AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'interpreter'

Tags: python, pycharm

It is a basic question, I guess. 
I can run my program in Pycharm 2018.1 Python 3.6.5. But when I run in debug mode and open python console, I get this error message when I try to key in any python command.

I am using virtualenv and added interpreter in project setting.

I wonder what's wrong with my configuration

below is stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 362, in get_interpreter
    interpreterInterface = getattr(__builtin__, 'interpreter')
AttributeError: module 'builtins' has no attribute 'interpreter'
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_comm.py", line 1443, in do_it
    result = pydevconsole.console_exec(self.thread_id, self.frame_id, self.expression, dbg)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 467, in console_exec
    need_more =  exec_code(CodeFragment(expression), updated_globals, frame.f_locals, dbg)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 383, in exec_code
    interpreterInterface = get_interpreter()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py", line 364, in get_interpreter
    interpreterInterface = InterpreterInterface(None, None, threading.currentThread())
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.interpreter = get_pydev_frontend(host, client_port)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 461, in get_pydev_frontend
    _PyDevFrontEndContainer._instance = _PyDevFrontEnd()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 310, in __init__
    self.ipython = PyDevTerminalInteractiveShell.instance()
  File "/Users/hobart/envs/pys/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config/configurable.py", line 412, in instance
    inst = cls(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hobart/envs/pys/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/terminal/interactiveshell.py", line 430, in __init__
    super(TerminalInteractiveShell, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/hobart/envs/pys/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 516, in __init__
    self.init_completer()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 234, in init_completer
    self.Completer = self._new_completer_500()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 196, in _new_completer_500
    parent=self
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_ipython_console_011.py", line 87, in __init__
    self.matchers.remove(self.python_matches)
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: I met another strange problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49687860/pycharm-unresolved-reference-on-join-of-os-path?noredirect=1#comment86434052_49687860

Comment: this problem is resurfacing in PyCharm 2019.2.2 (Community Edition)
Build #PC-192.6603.34, built on September 10, 2019
Runtime version: 11.0.3+12-b304.56 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Linux 4.15.0-58-generic
GC: ParNew, ConcurrentMarkSweep
Memory: 1981M
Cores: 8
Registry: 
Non-Bundled Plugins: org.intellij.plugins.markdown
Only in debug mode, not in regular execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed few days after your question: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-29313
You should update your PyCharm to 2018.1.1 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same problem after trying to install some packages into the virtual environment. For me it was solved by recreating the environment.